# CSS Sprites images rendered with bad quality in IE

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a CSS image sprite and this renderes perfect in FF, also IE.
The problem is the rendered image looks to have poor quality in IE.

Has anyone encountered this before? How did you fix it? I need CSS sprites to save bandwidth and requests.

[alt text http://cupacupelor.ro/img/problem.png](http://cupacupelor.ro/img/problem.png)

```
.blackmncenter2
{
    float:left;
    height:32px;
    line-height:32px;
    background-image:url(../img/top-menu-center.png);   
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:left -64px;
    color:White;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
}
```

#### Image:

> http://cupacupelor.ro/img/problem.png

#### Demo:

> http://cupacupelor.ro/

The black top menu, available max 7 days from posting.
Try it with FF, then with IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to have the graphic in PNG format? Traditionally, Internet Explorer 6.0 and earlier had some issues relating to the PNG format, most notably the lack of support for the alpha channel.

Without this alpha channel, IE can't render the transparency represented in PNG images correctly. This might distort the image a bit, or give you something other than what you were expecting to see.

Without more details it's hard to discern what's causing the problem (or what the problem is in the first place).

Comment: It's a PNG image but with no transparency in it
I have IE7 installed
Ok, i'll try to make the image JPG and i'll post back, I use PNG because they look better than JPG images

Answer (score 1):

Please define "poor quality". Maybe it's because your CSS sprite didn't preserve the original image's transparency?

Comment: please see this
cupacupelor dot ro/img/problem.png

poor quality means IE re-encode the image in a poor format

Comment: I have to concur; it's because of IE's inadequate support of transparent .png images. (unless it's not really an image and I'm misunderstanding. What's the URL of the affectd page?)

Answer (score 0):

Strange behavior, not expected.

Even if I have IE 7 and PNG with no transparency, backgrounds rendered with **background-position** style work weird in IE.

Saving the image as JPG and modify the CSS solved the problem.

Than you guys, I voted the answers.