# CSS sprites and IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css-sprites

Does IE6 support css-sprites?

Answer (score 10):

Yes IE 6 supports sprites but doesn't support 24 bit PNG transparency.

I use this css hack for giving IE < 7 a gif file and everything else a 24 bit png with transparency.

```
background-image:url(/images/sprites/icons-sprite.png);
_background-image:url(/images/sprites/icons-sprite.gif); /* IE<7 gets the crappy icons */
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Glue http://gluecss.com/
It's an open-source command line tool to generate sprites.

Answer (score 3):

CSS sprites is a general solution using backround-position, which is avaible even in IE5.

A good tutorial about them is located here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the IE6 CSS sprites problem myself - [I blogged it here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702040415/http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/200905/Blog/I-Said-Overflow-Hidden):

There's a really easy fix - I quote myself here...

> Luckily, the solution wasn't too bad. Internet Explorers passim seem to ignore overflow:hidden when a child element is set to position:relative. Not good news... but the solution is easy - set the element with overflow:hidden to also be position:relative and then change the position:relative declaration on the child to be position:absolute... the jobs a goodun.

The full details can be found on that link.

Comment: Hi Steve, that link is broken (ie not article at http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/200905/Blog/I-Said-Overflow-Hidden/ )

Comment: @DinisCruz link amended so you can read the original article.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

CSS sprites is just a technique to use offset on background images to display different parts of the same image in different elements.

I use CSS sprites on for example the main menu on [the website](http://www.bytbil.com) of the company I work for, and the flags on my own [web site](http://www.guffa.com). I started using it before it was even called CSS sprites...

Answer (score 1):

Browsers which support background-position property will support CSS sprites also.

[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Please take a look at the following questions also

[CSS Sprites images rendered with bad quality in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922748/css-sprites-images-rendered-with-bad-quality-in-ie)

[CSS Sprite Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976392/css-sprite-help)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you're using PNGs though you should consider a few things. Here is a decent summary of IE 6 PNG issues:

http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an online [sprites generator](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=sprite+generator&btnG=Google+Search&pws=0&complete=0&aq=f&oq=). There are so many of them available for free and most of them support all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Sprites can work perfectly in ie6. But a png image will not work, so use a gif. If you process a gif with Smush.it to losslessly remove overhead, you might get a file size smaller than the corresponding png.

Comment: Why would a png file not work? Semi-transparent pngs won't look good, but 8bit pngs will work just as gif images.